# How to handle a GET request error using XMLHttpRequest() and Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to handle an error when the input is not a valid URL. When I insert the input with a URL that does not exist, I am not getting the 404 status. I get the message:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load`

This is how I am trying to handle the error:

```
    const imgURL = document.querySelectorAll('img');

    imgURL.forEach(e => {

      const url = e.getAttribute('src');
      const http = new XMLHttpRequest();

      http.open('GET', url, false);
      http.send();

      if (http.status === 404) {
        console.log('You got an ERROR!')
      };
    });
```

What do I have to do to get the `http.status === 404`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can track the error like this and get the status from event parameter 'e' in `onerror` callback function.

```js
const imgURL = ["http://a.com", "https://b.com"];

imgURL.forEach(e => {

      const url = e;
      const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      
      
      http.open('GET', url);
      
      http.onerror = (e) => {
  console.log('DONE: ', e);
};

      http.send();


    });
```